# Custom Combine Publisher for a single database listener

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have an iOS app with a custom database, To retrieve data from my database I setup a listener like this:

```
var listener: DatabaseListener?

self.listener = db.items.addListener { items in 

}

// later when I don't need the listener any more:
self.listener?.cancel()
```

This listener gives the items as soon as I set it up and notifies me whenever my data is updated, It also stays alive until I manually cancel it. I also store a cache of the retrieved items in `UserDefaults` to speed things up (See it in action in the example bellow).

Now I'm trying to start using `Combine` to retrieve my items, I want to setup the database listener as soon as a new subscription is created (for example when `sink` or `assign` are called) and cancel it when there's no more subscriptions left.

So here's what I came up with:

```
class ItemsSubscription: Subscription {
    private var subscriber: (any Subscriber<[Item], Never>)?
    private var listener: DatabaseListener?
    private var items: [Item] = UserDefaults.standard.cacheItems

    init(subscriber: any Subscriber<[Item], Never>) {
        self.subscriber = subscriber
    }

    func request(_ demand: Subscribers.Demand) {
        let _ = subscriber?.receive(items)

        self.listener = db.items.addListener {
            UserDefaults.standard.cacheItems = $0
            self.items = $0
            let _ = self.subscriber?.receive($0)
        }
    }

    func cancel() {
        self.listener?.cancel()
        self.listener = nil
        self.subscriber = nil
    }
}

struct ItemsPublisher: Publisher {
    typealias Output = [Item]
    typealias Failure = Never

    func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S: Subscriber, S.Input == [Item], S.Failure == Never {
        let subscription = ItemsSubscription(subscriber: subscriber)
        subscriber.receive(subscription: subscription)
    }
}
```

Then I'm using `ItemsPublisher` like this:

```
private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

ItemsPublisher()
    .sink { items in

    }
    .store(&cancellables)
```

Currently this method is working but it's creating a new database listener (which is an expensive resource) for every `ItemsPublisher` I create. Instead I want to maintain a single database listener while I have a least 1 subscriber and I want any following subscriber to receive the latest items from the same subscription.

I considered creating a single `ItemsPublisher` instance and using it throughout the app, but later subscribers didn't receive any data at all.

I also considered using `CurrentValueSubject` (or a `@Published` property) to store the items but I couldn't figure out when to setup database listener or when to cancel it for that matter.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Instead I want to maintain a single database listener while I have a least 1 subscriber and I want any following subscriber to receive the latest items from the same subscription.

That's exactly what `share()` is for. [View the documentation for more information.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail/share())

You might also want to consider using multicast with a CurrentValueSubject depending on the situation.

Comment: I've just tried `share()` and It's seems to have the same behavior, It doesn't notify later subscribers with the current value as soon as they subscribe.

Comment: I'm going to do some research on how to use `multicast` with a `CurrentValueSubject`, Thanks for the advice on that. If you have any example or a code snippet on that I'd really appreciate it if you share it in the answer.

Comment: Right, because your database listener publisher doesn't know they subscribed anymore. Like I said in the answer, use multicast with a CurrentValueSubject in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, It was as easy as just calling `.multicast { CurrentValueSubject([]) }.autoconnect()`